# Can I stop a UITableViewCell from shrinking when I enter edit mode?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

When you enter edit mode for a UITableView (grouped but I believe this applies for the other types as well), the cells shrink to the right to accommodate the delete selection buttons. For cells that I dont wish to add/insert/delete any content, is there anyway to stop this behavior? ie. the width remains fixed.

I've tried setting accessoryType to UITableViewCellAccessoryNone but that just makes the red circle with the minus disappear.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use this in your tableViewController

tableView:shouldIndentWhileEditingRowAtIndexPath:

Return NO for the cells you don't want resizing.