# Appearance of table cells when deleting

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I'm trying to make a table view with an appearance much like the default Weather application provided by Apple. However I'm struggling a bit to make the table cells look correctly.

I would like all the cells, except the first one to be deletable. The problem is that the default cells have the small delete button on the left side of the cell instead of inside the cell. This causes the cells to shrink to the right, except the first one which keeps its size since it's not deletable.
[image] [image]

So my question is if there is any way to tweak the default UITableViewCell to have the same behavior as the cell used in the Weather app? Or do I have to implement my own cell with button animation, etc, etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that somebody else had already answered this in a slightly different [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1383428/can-i-stop-a-uitableviewcell-from-shrinking-when-i-enter-edit-mode):

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView shouldIndentWhileEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return NO;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it looks like that all apple is doing is making the background black for the delete button content area. i would try doing something like that first.