# Make a TableRow deletable

Tags: android, view

How can I make a View can be deleted after a longClick. In my case, I'm trying to make this with a TableRow. How can I do that white border with a red circle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This post solved my problem: [Turn Views Editable on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6461532/turn-views-editable-on-android)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the question about the white border/red circle is about but here is a good direction to delete a tableRow after long-clicking on it.

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo){
    TableLayout yourTable = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.yourTableId);
    TableRow yourTableRow = yourTable.getChildAt(INDEX_OF_YOUR_ROW_IN_THE_TABLE);
    if(v.getId() == yourTableRow.getId()){
        yourTable.removeView(yourTableRow);
    }
}
```

This should work if you know the index of the row you're trying to click on and your TableRow has an ID.

Comment: [Exactly like this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3266578/appearance-of-table-cells-when-deleting) .. but using android.