# Turn Views Editable on Android

Tags: java, android, tablerow

Is it possible to turn a view editable like [this image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3266578/appearance-of-table-cells-when-deleting)?

I know I can do that using a GridView. But, Im trying to do that with TableRows, is it possible?

**Edited:** What I really wanna to do is to construct some interface to delete a TableRow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you can remove TableRow from your TableLayout. You'll have to keep track of the different views (rows) in your table and then just call [`removeView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#removeView%28android.view.View%29) when you want to delete one.

Edit (answer to your question in the comments) :

Yes, you can edit the View dynamically. For example, if your TableRow is an horizontal LinearLayout, you can call [`addView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#addView%28android.view.View,%20int,%20android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams%29)

Like you did (making the button invisible) works too... to not make it take space in the TableRow, use [gone](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android%3avisibility) instead.

Comment: I know How to delete, I would like to make a interface for this.

Comment: What part of the interface are you not able to do ? Does not look too complicated to me.... is it the animations ?

Comment: My first question is if its possible to make a View editable, like a image that I linked in my ask. If isnt I would like to make some animation, do you have a example? I tried using an invisible button that appears after a longClick, but the button takes up space inside the invisible TableRow